# Replace YYYY in all series name across charts and multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change all the data in `YYYY` in my charts from `XX-2019` to `XX-2020`.

I'm trying to replace all 2019 with 2020, but I can't seem to get the code below to work.

Is there something that I am missing with the `FullSeriesCollection` usage?

```
Sub ChartLabelReplace()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xFindStr As String
    Dim xReplace As String
    xFindStr = Application.InputBox("Find:", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
    xReplace = Application.InputBox("Replace:", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    For Each ch In xWs.ChartObjects
        If ch.Chart.HasLegend Then
            ch.Chart.FullSeriesCollection.Name = _
                VBA.Replace(ch.Chart.FullSeriesCollection.Name, _
                xFindStr, xReplace, 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your code doing anything for the chart names for the Active Sheet you are on?

Comment: There is a box that asks me for the text that I would like to replace (i.e. '2019') followed by another box that I would like the values to be replaced with ('2020). After which, the error occurs to the line.
````
ch.Chart.FullSeriesCollection.Name = VBA.Replace(ch.Chart.FullSeriesCollection.Name, xFindStr, xReplace, 1)
````